# Вопрос по компараторам

Tags: c++, compare

Почему при равных значениях, поступивших на вход компаратору, мы должны возвращать
`false`, иначе это вызывает `Run Time Error`. Об этом узнал тут: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/70358?#comment-548342

Comment: Скажем так - для тех алгоритмов стандартной библиотеки, которые ждут компаратор `less`, т.е. "меньше" - такой компаратор приведет просто к неверной работе, не более того. Потому что будет нарушен сам принцип упорядочения... Например, проверка на равенство выполняется как `!(x<y)&&!(y<x)` - и что будет для равенства в вашем варианте? :)

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: *" мы должны возвращать false"* - ничего подобного мы не должны, другое дело, что этого могут требовать некоторые контейнеры и алгоритмы.

Comment: Нашёл схожий вопос на английском SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929474/why-must-stdsort-compare-function-return-false-when-arguments-are-equal